# DefaultHttpClient Deprecated Android Studio 2.2.2

Tags: java, android, apache, http

After following a few guides on how to get data and send data to a database on a local server using Apache, an error occurred saying that the code is deprecated. After looking for guides on the deprecation I found out the most of them are outdated.
Here are the codes of my manifest, the Parser , and the Gradle file module(by order):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.denis.loginappphpmyadmintest" >
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
package com.example.denis.loginappphpmyadmintest;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, ContentValues params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method.equals("POST")){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.denis.loginappphpmyadmintest"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',     {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

What steps do I need to take in order to solve this problem?
Also in the UrlEncodedFormEntity can't receive the ContentValues object , how do I solve that too?

Comment: an additional problem in your code is this comparison: ``method == "POST"``. Compare ``String`` values with the ``equals`` method, not ``==``.

Comment: thank you I have changed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update] 
I highly recommend to use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) instead of `org.apache.http`. It is way faster (coding time) and simpler to maintain/code.

**Get Request**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

**Post Request**

```
public static final MediaType JSON
= MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

Have'nt find better than this so far!

Just add the following dependency

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
```

The full code.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;


public class JSONParser {

    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public static JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, ContentValues params) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request;
            // check for request method
            if (method.equals("POST")) {
                // request method is POST
                final MediaType JSON
                        = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                final RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, params.toString());
                request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .post(body)
                        .build();
            } else if (method.equals("GET")) {
                // request method is GET
                  request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .build();
            }
            final Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            json = response.body().string();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e ){
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: And do I just add the code to the Parser or do I replace all of the file with what you wrote? I never used these requests as I haven't learned them or used them before

Comment: I'm commenting with my phoe now, I'll give you the full equivalent and what you need to do exaclty as soon as I get my pc.

Comment: @Swane, I've updated my answer. Kindly check it and let me now if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the code works but there are a few more errors in the app along the way, to post them here or to open a new question for that?

Comment: Glad that it helped. I think you should open a new question.

Comment: is there any chance you look at this one too?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634446/app-cant-reach-php-file-or-error-in-php-file-android-studio