# App Can't Reach PHP file or Error in PHP File Android Studio

Tags: php, android

My app tries to create a new row in a server.
The error I get is Null Point Exception at `jObj = new JSONObject(json);`

This is the php file that creates a new row:

```
<?php
$response = array();
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass']) &  isset($_POST['mail'])&&     isset($_POST['num']))
{
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$num = $_POST['num'];
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect2.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO users(Name, Password, Email,ConfirmNum) VALUES('$user', '$pass', '$mail', '$num')");
if ($result) {
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "user successfully created.";
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "missing fields";
echo json_encode($response);
} 
?>
```

The parser that requests for the update is:

```
package com.example.denis.onthego;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;


public class JSONParser {

static JSONObject jObj;
static String json;

// constructor
public JSONParser() {
}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public static JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, ContentValues params) {
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request;
        // check for request method
        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            // request method is POST

            MediaType contentType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            String content = "";
            for (String key : params.keySet())
            {
                if ( !content.isEmpty())
                    content += "&";

                content += key + "=" + params.get(key);
            }

            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(contentType, content);
            request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(body).build();
        }
        else  {
            // request method is GET
            request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        }
        final Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        json = response.body().string();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e ){
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
}
```

And the call for the parser is :

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,"POST", params);
```

While the "add_user" is for the php file that makes a new row(It is the correct url) and "params" are not empty and contain the right keys and content.
Is there something wrong with the parser or the php file?
This is a very serious school project and this is the only thing I am missing.

Here are the params:

```
 params.put("user", "swane15");
 params.put("pass", "asdeg124A");
 params.put("mail", "asf@asd.com");
 params.put("num", "111111");
```

Why doesn't the php file return anything? Is because the app can't reach it or is there an error with the php file itself?

Comment: Well what is the problem? What goes wrong? And what is the question? If you continue to post in such an vague way you can post a hundred times.

Comment: Actually the previous posts contained the question, and the question may be clear from the title. So I would really like to see an answer from anyone.

Comment: Questions are not put in titles but follow a problem description in the body of a post. If required fields are missing then you should tell us which fields. And as you are not showing which params you send then how do you think we would know what is missing?

Comment: the params that are set are id=1 and the name price and description is whatever is written in the edit text.I have checked that the params are set by printing the params on a Toast and the values were set

Comment: `id=1`. That should be `pid=1` according to your php script. But we cannot see which params you send. And during tests you should just send fixed strings. Saves you time.

Comment: I did place pid=1 I mistakenly wrote id=1. I tried to place fixed strings but it did not make any difference, now i'm testing what is missing exactly

Comment: `makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,"POST", params);`. Well if you refuse to show code where we can see what the params are then little help can be given.

Comment: I was just updating the post, sorry for not writing it I thought that it is irrelevant as I wrote that the params are not empty

Comment: `final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8");`. Can you explain what this statement does? What is it telling the server?

Comment: I asked for the parser on this forum, from what I understand its the encoding scheme

Comment: Please elaborate. Nobody understands your answer. You are not even telling what the encoding scheme would be. What you are telling the server what you are gonna send. What kind of data it can expect. Your params are content values. `ContentValues params`.

Comment: So what do I write instead of the current MediaType

Comment: "Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8");. You are telling the server that you are gonna send your parameters in json. A json array as text. But you are not doing that. And you should not as the php script expects posted parameters.  You should change that to form url encoded. Google for the exact notation.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a notation for that, I have looked though for ways to send a json array but all my attempts were unsuccessful. I am clueless about what notation to change it to so it will work or how to send a json array

Comment: Unbelievable that you cannot find the correct notation. Just a small google will give it. And of course you should not send json as your php schript is not expecting json but normal posted parameters.

Comment: I searched for almost an hour and I didn't find the notation, maybe I can send a text so it can add it to this line: `$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO products(pid , name, price, description) VALUES('$pid', '$name', '$price', '$description')");`

Comment: Place text/html, still doesn't work. It will be done a lot faster if you just told me what to write at the media type. Same goes to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Well that last one should do it.

Comment: I placed `"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` and it still doesn't work

Comment: Please tell about your server.

Comment: `MediaType.parse("Content-Type:application/json;`. That should be more  `MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");`

Comment: Still writes that the fields are missing. The server an application that is called "XAMPP" and it contains two programs: "Apache" and "MySQLi". 
Basically Apache gives the emulator access to the PHP files through a local server and MySQLi runs the data base.

Comment: And where is your server resided? Are you really using an emulator?

Comment: `params.toString()` Please tell the value.

Comment: I am using the emulator because it is easier to write the "url" of the php files. the server is running real time on the machine.
"pid=1 name=lol price=123.00 description=text" not including the quotes

Comment: Then it makes no sense trying to send params.toString(). I wonder why you have so much troubles doing a simple post with okhttp. There are so many examples on the internet and they look a bit different from your code.

Comment: I am copying an app that someone else made so that i can use some of its properties for my app. Most of the code was depricated and im new to this topic so im having trouble

Answer (score 0):

```
 MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8");
 RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, params.toString());
```

Change to:

```
      MediaType contentType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

      String content = "";        
      for (String key : params.keySet())
      {
          if ( !content.isEmpty())
              content += "&";

          content += key + "=" + params.get(key);
      }

      RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(contentType, content);
```

To do it right you should URLEncoder.encode() the values.

Comment: if you could please look at this one more time, for some reason my previous project works fine but this one doesn't. All I did was change the parameters